# Reference ConfigMap / Secret in Kubernetes object metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, kops

I have a *Kubernetes* cluster provisioned at *AWS* with *kops* and I use *route 53 mapper* to configure *ELB* based on `Service` annotations and use namespaces for different environments `dev`, `test`, `prod` with configuration being defined in *ConfigMap* and *Secret* objects.

Environments have different hostname and TSL certificates:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: http-proxy-service
  labels:
    dns: route53
  annotations:
    domainName: <env>.myapp.example.io
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: |-
      arn:aws:acm:eu-central-1:44315247xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https

spec:
  selector:
    app: http-proxy
  ports:
    - name: https 
      port: 443
```

Is there a Kubernetes way to reference `ConfigMap`/`Secret` objects in the `metadata` section of the object descriptor so I can have only one file for all environments?

I am looking for pure Kubernetes solution not using any templating before sending file to API via `kubecetl`.

Answer (score 0):

There is not.

FWIW, it seems nuts that that mapper was designed to pull cert data from annotations on a Service. Service objects are not otherwise secret.

The mapper should be able to consume cert data from a Secret that has well defined fields to indicate what domain should be wired with what cert data in front of what service.